Readied action Sneak Attack after Action Surge
I was running a game the other night when one of the players pulled a tactic I was unsure about. I ruled against it and was then sent a reddit thread, however during a large life or death combat is not the time to stop and browse reddit. It also did not answer my question.
Here is the order of events:
Rogue (Soulknife 9) / Fighter (Purple Dragon Knight 5)
Attack (Sneak Attack used), Attack, Action Surge, Ready action to attack
Then once the held action is triggered, Attack (Sneak Attack used).
On the trigger, the target had been knocked prone but has two enemies within 5ft. The readied action was a thrown Psychic Blade attack. My question is:
"Is that allowed?" First time anyone has done this.

Is what allowed? Sneak attack on a hold action?

By hold action you mean Ready action, right?

Eddy - Yes Held/Ready - Used Intercranial there. I will update for readability.

Tree - Sneak attack On the Held Action after having used the sneak attack prior

Are those 2 enemies,enemies of the players or enemies of the targeted creature?

The 2 enemies of the targeted creature were friendly PCs to the player making the attack

Recall that if you want to reply to a comment you can use @[Username]: for example, if I wanted to reply yo TreeSpawned I can write @TreeSpawned.

No...but possibly not for the reasons you'd expect.
Let's break this down, step by step. First of all, a Purple Dragon is a fighter subclass found in the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide 1, and at 5th level, fighters get the Extra Attack feature which states:

Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Emphasized to remember for later. A Rogue's Sneak Attack features says:

Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack...

Emphasis mine, but this shows us that regardless of how many times a player can attack on their turn, they are limited to a single use of Sneak Attack. So making two attacks and using their Sneak Attack feature once is allowed. Next is their use of the fighter class' Action Surge which is:

On your turn, you can take one additional action.

There are no limits to what kind of action they can take (unlike with the Haste spell), so using this additional action to take the Ready Action is certainly permissible:

...you can take the Ready action on your turn, which lets you act using your reaction before the start of your next turn.

Since Sneak Attack is limited to only one attack during a player's turn, IF it is no longer the player's turn when they use their Reaction, then they can indeed use it to make an attack that qualifies for Sneak Attack, as long as all of the other criteria for Sneak Attack are met. Remember that an attack made using a Reaction is not using the Attack action, and as such would not qualify for use of the Extra Attack feature. It would therefore only ever be a single attack, see above.

HOWEVER...
You stated that the target was Prone:

An attack roll against the creature has advantage if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature. Otherwise, the attack roll has disadvantage.

Typically, when the player is within five feet of a target, then a thrown weapon attack would have disadvantage per the rules for Ranged Attacks in Close Combat.

When you make a ranged attack with a weapon, a spell, or some other means, you have disadvantage on the attack roll if you are within 5 feet of a hostile creature who can see you and who isn't incapacitated.

If the player were within five feet of their Prone target, and for some reason chose to give up making a melee attack with advantage in order to make a ranged attack...well, not only would I question their sanity but they'd have a straight attack roll since having advantage and disadvantage cancel each other out 1.
Since the OP specified that the Psychic Blade was thrown by the rogue, I'm going to assume that the rogue was NOT within melee range of the target. As such, they'd have disadvantage on their attack roll and without some other factor canceling that out, this would prevent them from using their Sneak Attack feature:

You don’t need advantage on the attack roll if another enemy of the target is within 5 feet of it, that enemy isn’t incapacitated, and you don’t have disadvantage on the attack roll.

In short, they could do all of that, but the Prone condition on their target disallows the second Sneak Attack damage unless they were in melee range.

1: Thank you TreeSpawned!

The Purple Dragon Knight is a Fighter Subclass from the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide

As the Target is standing next to 2 enemies, the sneak attack would occur, as long as the attack doesn't have disadvantage.

For clarity it would be useful to state how many attacks they get with that reaction, the OP seems to think it is 2

Thank you @TreeSpawned and SeriousBri, adjustments made!

@SeriousBri No I don't. Nowhere in my question does it reflect that. Attack (action) and then Sneak Attack (feature).

Great answer. So yes they can sneak attack out of turn (attack as reaction is a common tactic as a Rogue to get a second Sneak Attack), but not in the case when they have disadvantage, which attacking a prone creature not from within 5ft does.

If they were within 5 feet of the target they would get sneak attack because, they have advantage from being within 5 feet and disadvantage from ranged attack in melee range, which cancel eachother out. And as there are 2 enemies (of the target) standing next to the target, the rogue would get sneak attack.

@TreeSpawned hmm, interesting. Usually I interpret "no disadvantage" part of sneak attack requirement to not be fulfilled if you have both adv and dis. Afterall, if you had no dis (from 5ft ranged), you would have adv, so the dis is definitely there. This is also the interpretation in BG3. Tho searching around, I now realize both views are quite common apparently

@justhalf The rogue could have used a melee attack with his blade. As written in rules, it is "a simple melee weapon with the finesse and thrown properties". Unlike bow, it is not limited to ranged attacks. And so the rogue gets advantage against prone target, thus able to Sneak Attack.

Yea, I wasn't discussing SA with melee, which is possible. I was referring to the comment on "having both dis and adv means you have no dis"

So, if the player was nex to his target, the second Sneak Attack would have worked. Except, he likely wasn't.

@justhalf PHB p.173, Advantage and Disadvantage: "If circumstances cause a roll to have both advantage and disadvantage, you are considered to have neither of them, and you roll one d20". So a thrown attack witin 5ft has both adv (being against a prone enemy within 5ft) and dis (as a ranged attack within 5ft), thus having no disadvantage. But since allies are nearby, that fulfills the second part of the sneak attack rule - no dis and allies within 5ft of target.

@FortTell thanks for the reference, that's what I was missing.

@justhalf See also Does advantage negate disadvantage (for things such as the rogue's Sneak Attack)?

@FortTell See also Does advantage negate disadvantage (for things such as the rogue's Sneak Attack)?

"...an attack made using a Reaction is not using the Attack action, and as such would not qualify for use of the Extra Attack feature" - that's not why. It's still the Attack Action that you readied. But Extra Attack says "...on your turn...", which the readied action isn't.
